# Active TabPage has same color as my controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have made a TabControl and want to use some controls (labels, textboxes, buttons and combobox drop-downs). The problem is that when I select a tab, the default background color is not the same as the default background color of the form the controls used to be on. The color of the tab and the controls are too similar and it doesn't look good.

I have looked, but people seem to say that it's impossible to color tabs. What is a good solution to this? Should I put some kind of frame, label or something else inside the tab to make the background darker?

Comment: is it a wpf application or a winforms application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's easy to get your tab pages to use the same background color as your form:**

1. Make sure that the `TabPage` you want to change is visible in the designer. Click on it to select it.
2. In the Properties Window, find the [`UseVisualStyleBackColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabpage.usevisualstylebackcolor.aspx) property, and set it to `False`.

And as a bonus, once you've set this property to `False`, you can specify any background color that you want for the `TabPage` using its [`BackColor` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160620.aspx).

The reason that this works is that you're forcing the tab page not to render with visual styles (i.e., themes as defined by Windows). The default theme actually paints tab pages a slightly lighter shade of the color used to paint other 3D elements (like forms and buttons). The problem (under the Aero theme in particular) is that the color of the standard 3D elements is so light already that the tab pages almost look white!

If you're satisfied with the contrast of the controls against the standard background color of your form, I suggest that you simply set the `UseVisualStyleBackColor` property to `False` and leave it at that without specifying a custom background color. Respecting the user's default theme is generally the best practice, rather than trying to skin an application yourself.

**EDIT:** Note that this will *not* change the color of the tabs themselves at the top of the `TabControl`. To do that, you're going to have to specify it as owner-drawn and handle its `DrawItem` event, forcing you to do all of the painting yourself. In most cases, however, this is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the simple solution for now. So I set the UseVisualStyleBackColor to false. I am not making a flashy application, so that solution is good enough for now. Though I agree that forcing a tab to not render visual styles is not very elegant.

Comment: @Kasper: Oh, I didn't say it wasn't elegant. ;-) I use it all the time in my applications because I agree with you that the very light background it uses by default makes it hard to see the controls it contains. What I think is ugly are non-standard skin colors. Anyway, I'm glad it worked for you.